# No value(s) from doctrine query

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am not retrieving any values with a simple Doctrine PHPCR query I am executing.

In this piece of code I get all the values from field 'name':

```
public function getPagesAction()
{
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine_phpcr.odm.default_document_manager');
    $qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->from()->document('Foo\BarBundle\Document\StandardPage', 'p');

    return $this->render(
        'FooBarBundle:Toolbar:navigation.html.twig',
        array('names' => $qb->getQuery()->execute())
    );
}
```

**output:** *home, mypage, testpage, foo*

And with this code I get nothing in return:

```
public function getPagesAction()
{
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine_phpcr.odm.default_document_manager');
    $qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->from()->document('Foo\BarBundle\Document\StandardPage', 'p');
    $qb->where()->like()->field('p.name')->literal('mypage');

    return $this->render(
        'FooBarBundle:Toolbar:navigation.html.twig',
        array('names' => $qb->getQuery()->execute())
    );
}
```

I am also not receiving any errors. My HTML is plain empty. The query does work when I replace 'p.name' with 'p.title'.

Here is my [StandardPage.php on Gist](https://gist.github.com/TisLars/0aecd7bbc2cab31c57cf)

Comment: Can you show your `Foo\BarBundle\Document\StandardPage` class?

Comment: Added StandardPage.php file on Gist below my first post.